# How to list emails available on mobile?

Tags: android

Some Apps show automatically **without** any permission, emails available into a popup:

[image]

I checked on the web, and I can't find how can I do that. A lot of tutos use permission into manifest and I don't want that.

Thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 0):

Use [GoogleSignInOptions](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInOptions.Builder.html#GoogleSignInOptions.Builder()) to implement this & use the `requestEmail()` option that it provides with. Add the following codes to achieve the desired output:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .build();
mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

For the sign-in flow, after receiving the button click by user, simply call this method:

```
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

And then fetch a `GoogleSignInAccount` object for that user in `onActivityResult()` method like the following:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
        updateUI(account);
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
        updateUI(null);
    }
}
```

Please refer to the [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people) here to explore more.

Comment: thank you very much! But the popup which appears it's not totally the same like my screenshot (I want to remove the popup header, and I don't want to create a new gmail account button)